# Visual Studio 2013, Report editor crashing when adding DataSource

Tags: visual-studio, crash, editor, report

I've been at this problem for days now.
When I try to add a datasource on a report in VS2013, VS crashes.
It doesn't happen in all projects and in the event log I can see the following:

```
    Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
Stack:
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.Dialogs.Pages.DataSetGeneralPage.LoadDataSources()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.Dialogs.Pages.DataSetGeneralPage.LoadData()
   at Microsoft.ReportDesigner.Data.Local.Dialogs.DataSetDialog.OnLoad(System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
```

So..  Its the reading of datasources that is crashing, that seems obvious and since its related to a specific project (a large one) there is propably some data provider added somewhere that causes this.

I can't see what file that it cant find though, and I cant find the list of datasources that this particular function tries to access.

Is there anywhere I can modify this (supposed) list of datasources that the report editor is using?

Any other syggestions on how to find the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had problems with a reference (dll) that I had added. To find out, I was removing references one by one and test the report datasource